# Grab Docker Stats Results Using Python

Tags: python, unix, docker

I am trying to build a monitoring app that constantly gets a feed from `docker stats` API. I quickly noticed that whenever I try to run something like `docker stats 857ff7a0403b` from within python, it does not gather the `std out` and waits for ever. The example python code is below.

```
commands.getoutput('docker stats 857ff7a0403b')
```

While the above code works for running commands like `docker ps` and `docker images` but it does not work for `docker stats`.

Is there a way in python to quickly grab the results and terminate the utility so that it does not wait for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a docker option called `--no-stream` that will only grab once and output to standard out.

```
docker stats --no-stream 857ff7a0403b
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/ for more details.

Answer (score -1):

in python file/code write below command and run

```
import os
os.system("docker stats 857ff7a0403b")
```

1. in terminal when you write (**docker stats container-id**) hit enter then it will show you the stats of that specific container
2. in python OS library will help you to write the terminal commands in python as you are writing in terminal as above(it is for, if you want to access it through program)

Comment: Please be more specific on the answer and add explanation in your code.

Comment: if you want to get the stats of all the running container then the
following command will help you

this is just terminal command [**docker stats $(docker ps -q)**]

python code:
**
import os
os.system("docker stats $(docker ps -q)")**